# How to call face detection in opencv from within matlab?/failure with the loadlibrary 

Tags: matlab, opencv, mex, face-detection, loadlibrary

I am using matlab 2011b (32bit), VS 2008, OpenCV 242.

I would like to load the libraries and then call them by "calllib" in matlab. My problem is 
when I load the libraries:

```
opencvPath = 'C:\opencv';
includePath = 'C:\opencv\build\include';
[notfound,warnings]=loadlibrary(...
fullfile('C:\opencv\build\x86\vc9\bin', 'opencv_core242.dll'),...
fullfile(opencvPath, 'build\include\opencv\cxcore.h'), ...
'alias', 'cxcore', 'includepath', includePath)

[notfound,warnings]=loadlibrary(...
fullfile('C:\opencv\build\x86\vc9\bin', 'opencv_core242.dll'), ...
fullfile(opencvPath, 'build\include\opencv\cv.h'), ...
'alias', 'cv', 'includepath', includePath)

[notfound,warnings]=loadlibrary(...
'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc9\bin\opencv_highgui242.dll',...
'C:\opencv\build\include\opencv\highgui.h', ...
    'alias', 'highgui', 'includepath', includePath)
```

and for example I get this for highgui:

```
Warning: The library class 'highgui' already exists.  Use a classname alias. 
> In loadlibrary at 180
In facedetector at 45 

notfound =

  []
```

It seems they have been loaded. But now if I try to use calllib, I get an error the function cannot be found!!!

To understand if I really loading the libraries, I used "libfunctions('highgui')" which seems I did not really load the libraries!!! I get the below error:

```
"No methods for class lib.highgui or no class lib.highgui."
```

Comment: The below is the rest of the code I am trying to implement:

    classifierFilename =      'C:/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml';

%  cvCascade = calllib('cv', 'cvLoadHaarClassifierCascade',...
%                       classifierFilename)

%  cvStorage = calllib('cxcore242', 'cvCreateMemStorage', 0);
% 
%    cvImage = calllib('cvLoadImage', inputImage, int16(1));
% 
% if ~cvImage.Value.nSize
% 
%     error('Image could not be loaded');
% end

Comment: Please, edit your question and add this code there. It will improve reading.